# Nesting and updating dictonaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file(census.txt) which I am trying to abstract out into a nested dictionary. The file has been copied into the code for ease of programming.
The problem I have is, I am unable to somehow iterate and "update" the dictionaries.
Could you please throw some light?

I would like to try further if someone could provide some hints on updating the dictionaries..
Here is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
#
#######   census.txt   #################
#day0   nameOfCity  count   records 
#day0   city0       1   2       
#day0   city1       5   6       
#day0   city2       6   12      
#day1   nameOfCity  count   records 
#day1   city0       1   2       
#day1   city1       7   5       
#day1   city2       6   12      
#day2   nameOfCity  count   records 
#day2   city0       1   2       
#day2   city1       7   5       
#day2   city2       6   12      
#day2   city0       4   3
#######################################
#
#Note: # sum values of data for same city entered multiple times
#
#####  REQUIRED NESTED DICTIONARY OUTPUT  ###############
#
#{ day0: {city0 : {'count': 1, 'records' : 2}, city1: {'count' : 5, 'records' : 6}, city2: {'count' : 6, 'records' : 12}},
#  day1: {city0 : {'count': 1, 'records' : 2}, city1: {'count' : 7, 'records' : 5}, city2: {'count' : 6, 'records' : 12}},
#  day2: {city0 : {'count': 5, 'records' : 5}, city1: {'count' : 7, 'records' : 5}, city2: {'count' : 6, 'records' : 12}} }
#  
# #######################################################


import sys
import os

# ===================
# Main Python section
# ===================
if __name__ == '__main__':

    omit_list =['nameOfCity'] # omit the heading line each time and pick only values
    count_rows = 0 
    count_columns =  4 #known beforehand, 
    items = [0 for i in range (count_columns)]
    dict2 = {} #outermost dictionary with day as key
    dict1 = {} #inner dictionary with city names as keys
    dict0 = {} #innermost dictionary with count and records as keys
    with open('census.txt', 'r') as fname:
    for line in fname:
        if (not any(omitted_word in line for omitted_word in omit_list)) and line.strip():
            items =line.split()
            if len(items) == count_columns:
                dict0["count"]=items[2]
                dict0["records"]=items[3] 
                dict1[items[1]]= dict0 
                if items[0] not in dict2:
                        dict2[items[0]] = dict1
                        print 'if'
                else:
                    dict2[items[0]].update(dict1)
                    print 'else'    
                dict0 = {}
                print dict2
                count_rows +=1              
    #print count_rows
    print "*********** dict2 ************"
    print dict2  
    fname.close()
```

I am trying to abstract out the day-wise information for each city. Here the first problem while coding was, city0 on day2 for example has been entered multiple times.

I need to sum up the number of records and count before "creating" the innermost dictionary of records and counts as the key field "city0" is unique. The other thing is, "day" key is unique but contains many city field values. Somehow I could not achieve this nesting and the output of the code :

```
*********** dict2 ************
{'day2': {'city2': {'count': '6', 'records': '12'}, 'city0': {'count': '4', 'records': '3'}, 'city1': {'count': '7', 'records': '5'}}, 'day0': {'city2': {'count': '6', 'records': '12'}, 'city0': {'count': '4', 'records': '3'}, 'city1': {'count': '7', 'records': '5'}}, 'day1': {'city2': {'count': '6', 'records': '12'}, 'city0': {'count': '4', 'records': '3'}, 'city1': {'count': '7', 'records': '5'}}}
```

(which is clearly wrong as only the innermost dictionary is getting overwritten by day2 information alone)

The actual output that I expect is:

```
{ day0: {city0 : {'count': 1, 'records' : 2}, city1: {'count' : 5, 'records' : 6}, city2: {'count' : 6, 'records' : 12}},
  day1: {city0 : {'count': 1, 'records' : 2}, city1: {'count' : 7, 'records' : 5}, city2: {'count' : 6, 'records' : 12}},
  day2: {city0 : {'count': 5, 'records' : 5}, city1: {'count' : 7, 'records' : 5}, city2: {'count' : 6, 'records' : 12}} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work if your file is consistant:

```
days = {}

current_day = None
with open('census.txt') as fname:
    for l in fname:
        day, city, count, records = l.split()
        if current_day != day:
            current_day = day
            days[current_day] = {}
        else:
            count = int(count)
            records = int(records)
            if city in days[current_day]:
                days[current_day][city]['count'] += count
                days[current_day][city]['records'] += records
            else:
                days[current_day][city] = {'count': count, 'records': records}

print(days)
```

Also note: you don't need to `.close()` file if you use `with` statement. It will be closed automaticaly.

Comment: just to add that you should convert 'count' and 'records'  to integer to avoid to concatenate strings.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I tried the code above. thanks for the snippet. When I modified my code with it, it seems to return all but city0 information for day0 and day1..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the code from the above post. This is what worked for me:

```
days = {}
omit_list =['nameOf'] # omit the heading line each time and pick only values
current_day = None
with open('census.txt') as fname:
    for l in fname:
    if (not any(omitted_word in l for omitted_word in omit_list)) and l.strip():
        day, city, count, records = l.split()
        count = int(count)
        records = int(records)
        if current_day != day:
            current_day = day
            days[current_day] = {}
            days[current_day][city] = {'count': count, 'records': records}
        else:
            if city in days[current_day]:
            days[current_day][city]['count'] += count
            days[current_day][city]['records'] += records
            else:
            days[current_day][city] = {'count': count, 'records': records}

print(days)
```